# Magento 2 How to restrict customer registration country bases

Tags: magento2, customer-account

In magento 2.2.3 SPAM customer registration is pain, and also enabling capatcha is drooping sales.

Can we restrict customer registration country / IP bases?

Comment: have you enabled captcha only for registration form?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my question, enabling it will drop the sales

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, You can restrict the registration via using IP/country.**

I think, in this case, you can use [Amasty GeoIP Redirect](https://amasty.com/geoip-redirect-for-magento-2.html)

Or you can build an extension for yourself for this requirment.

first, you need to implement geo IP tracking system using some extension like https://github.com/magefan/module-geoip

Then ,from [getVisitorCountryCode](https://github.com/magefan/module-geoip/blob/master/Model/IpToCountryRepository.php#L85) function get current user country code easily,

Then using event

`controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost` and

`controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create`

you can protect this **customer registration form**   page from access from this country

**Observer may be look like:**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magentodemo\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class RestrictCustomerAccount implements ObserverInterface
{
    /*
    * @var \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data
    */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_session;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_urlManager;



    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    protected $IpToCountryRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magefan\GeoIp\Model\IpToCountryRepository $IpToCountryRepository

        ) {
            $this->_helper = $helper;
            $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
            $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
            $this->_session = $session;
            $this->_urlManager = $urlManager;
            $this->redirect = $redirect;
            $this->IpToCountryRepository = $IpToCountryRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Check Captcha On User Login Page
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            if ( $this->IpToCountryRepository->getVisitorCountryCode() =='US') {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Access denied'));
                $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $this->_session->setCustomerFormData($controller->getRequest()->getPostValue());
                $url = 'https://www.google.com/';
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->redirect->error($url));
            }


        return $this;
    }
}
```